# Why does the Ansible uri module get 400 with valid credenitals?

Tags: json, ansible, graylog

We are using the uri module for querying the Graylog API the data, which is in json format.

```
- name: Get data
  uri:
    url: http://graylog-host:9000/api/system
    url_username: username
    url_password: password
    force_basic_auth: yes
    return_content: yes
    method: GET
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: false
  register: node_id_output
```

Unfortunately, with this task we get following error:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "", "content_length": "0", "date": "Wed, 02 Sep 2020 07:21:25 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", "redirected": false, "status": 400, "url": "http://graylog-host:9000/api/system"}
```

Although following Curl command works fine and returns valid JSON content with status code 200:

```
curl -u username:password -H "Accept: application/json"  http://graylog-host:9000/api/system
```

What would be the cause of the error? Alternatively we can use body_format: form-urlencoded, which does not return 400, but unfortunately then the content is not parsable by json_query filter.

Comment: What if you remove the `body_format` parameter and add `headers: {Accept: application/json}`?

Comment: @zigarn is correct; one can see the `Content-Length: 4` and `Content-Type: application/json` with a body of `null` if you change the URL to http://requestbin.net or similar; since a `GET` with a body is very weird, graylog sends back the 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `body_format: json` will set the header `Content-Type: application/json` and send the value of the `body` parameter which will be `null`.

In your case, you want to set the header `Accept: application/json` to get JSON back instead of something else (XML I guess).

```yaml
- name: Get data
  uri:
    url: http://graylog-host:9000/api/system
    url_username: username
    url_password: password
    force_basic_auth: yes
    return_content: yes
    method: GET
    headers:
      Accept: application/json
    validate_certs: false
  register: node_id_output
```